# Can't build a go module built with Swig due to missing include path

Tags: go, swig

In my swig interface file I use includes such as:

```
%{
    #include "lib-cpp/types/lists/linked-list.hpp"
%}
%include "lib-cpp/types/lists/linked-list.hpp"
```

However when I run go install I get:

```
navdb_go_client_wrap.cxx:258:14: fatal error: 'lib-cpp/types/lists/linked-list.hpp' file not found
```

How do I specify an include directory for go install?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH to the required include path fixed this.